# Recursion with Function of Time and Date

Tags: java, recursion, google-calendar-api

i have write a Function which its become an Event of Google Calendar but its not working , i have an Exception which i understand from it that  this function is Endless.any Ideas??

```
    public boolean is_error(Event temp) throws IOException{
    int anz=1;
    if (temp!=null){
     if (temp.getSummary().equals(CalendarHelper.EventType.off)){
            return false;
     }
      if  (temp.getSummary().equals(CalendarHelper.EventType.work)){
            return true;
     }
    }


          anz++;
        return is_error(this.getLastWorkRelevantEvent(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-anz*24*60*60*1000L)));



    }
```

Comment: I have two: Indent your code properly, and post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here :

```
this.getLastWorkRelevantEvent(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-anz*24*60*60*1000L))
```

This always returns null and by that you will never get in your

```
if (temp!=null){
 if (temp.getSummary().equals(CalendarHelper.EventType.off)){
        return false;
 }
  if  (temp.getSummary().equals(CalendarHelper.EventType.work)){
        return true;
 }
}
```

Now you have a problem with the integer anz to, it will always be 2.

do this in stead:

```
public boolean is_error(Event temp, int anz) throws IOException{
    if (temp!=null){
        if (temp.getSummary().equals(CalendarHelper.EventType.off)){
            return false;
         }
         if  (temp.getSummary().equals(CalendarHelper.EventType.work)){
            return true;
         }
         //for fun do this:
         throw new RuntimeException("no equals is good");
     }
     return is_error(this.getLastWorkRelevantEvent(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-anz*24*60*60*1000L)),++anz);
}
```

now if you get the runTimeException the fault is in the 2 if's. Otherwise you get always null back from 'getLastWorkRelevantEvent(...)'

Greetz Chill.

Comment: chillworld i have change the code but i become this :

Comment: com.google.apphosting.api.DeadlineExceededException: This request (a9ad378e64490bd5) started at 2014/01/15 14:31:13.419 UTC and was still executing at 2014/01/15 14:32:12.915 UTC.
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1033)
 at

Comment: test your this.getLastWorkRelevantEvent(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-anz*24*60*60*1000L)) method with different anz. Then you shall see that you always get an null.
Fix that in order to get this working
If that is not null then the fault is in your first 2 if's

Comment: np, I edited mine answer also to help you faster to see where is the problem.